# What are the total fees in USD for a Schengen visa via the German embassy, by mail?

Tags: fees-and-charges, schengen-visas, mail

I am applying for a Schengen visa in the US, at the German embassy. We are two adults and our 2 year-old son. Our son is a US citizen, so I believe no documentation is needed for him, though I'm buying medical insurance for him as well. We are eligible for email application, because we had it 2 years back.

I am confused about the fees for both of us. The website says:

> Your envelope has to include the visa fee (60,- EUR payable in USD as per the exchange rate of the day you apply - you will be informed about the current equivalent in USD when contacting your responsible mission), your passport and, in case you wish to have your passport mailed back to you via FedEx/USPS, it also has to include a pre-filled FedEx/USPS slip with your address as well as an additional 25,- USD for the FedEx/USPS fee.

If I am sending both applications, all documents and passports in one envelope and expect it back via FedEx/USPS, for what amount should the money-order be made? Euro 60+60 = Euro 120 is considered to be how much in USD?

I am also not clear on the

> pre-filled FedEx/USPS slip with your address as well as an additional 25,- USD for the FedEx/USPS fee

Along with $25, what is that slip, which we need to send ?

I used the form at germany.info/us-en/kontakt-formular and still waiting for their reply. I called the San Francisco consulate, mentioned at germany.info/us-en/embassy-consulates but it's not responsive. I know it is Euro 60, but in USD terms, I don't know how much I should send.

Comment: I am not able to get this information. Though I have sent them email too, twice, but still waiting for their response. So, I posted it here, if somebody got any better website links, which defines this fees structure in better way. Or any recent experience with anybody, which can tell us, how much Euro 60 in USD, now-a-days.

Comment: Did you use the form at https://www.germany.info/us-en/kontakt-formular?  If not, maybe you should try that first.  Otherwise, if you haven't received a response for several days, you could try calling the "responsible mission".  You can identify the correct mission and find its telephone number at https://www.germany.info/us-en/embassy-consulates.  You might also edit your question to include the steps you've taken to try to get the information, which will make the question seem much more reasonable.

Comment: Have edited my original question

Comment: Since they say they use the daily exchange rate, the literal answer to the question in the title is still "you have to find out from the consulate," since you don't know how they get their rate.  So your real problem now is how to get that information from the consulate.  How long have you been waiting for an e-mail response?  What do you mean by saying they were "unresponsive"?  Did they not answer the phone?

Comment: I tried calling them 3-4 times since morning, but it is always a prerecorded message, which doesn't give me option to reach out to any real person.

Comment: Did you call between 8 AM and noon?  Did you try the non-visa number?

Comment: Yes, called between 8 AM to noon and non-visa number is busy with existing calls, so it is saying that we are busy with other customers.
Still trying.

Comment: Finally, I am able to get response from +1 415 775 10 61 and they mentioned $75+$75+$19 for both of us, which includes shipping as well. Thanks for your efforts and help here

Answer (score 1):

Per OP's comment, he was able to get a clarification from the German Consulate in San Francisco (phone 415-775-1061).

The fee was €60 for each application, at the current USD exchange rate  in this case $75. The added shipping fee covered both being mailed in the same package (in this case $19). The calculation was $75 + $75 + $19.